# Error on cordova plugin: callback returning error

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

On my www/RuptionARPlugin.js file I have the followig code:

```
RuptionARPlugin.prototype.loadWorld = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {

        cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "RuptionARPlugin", "open", []);

        

        // We add an event listener on the resume and pause event of the application life-cycle
        document.addEventListener("resume", this.onResume, false);
        document.addEventListener("pause", this.onPause, false);
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", this.onBackButton, false);
    };
```

On my RuptionARPlugin.java I have the following

```
(...)
public class RuptionARPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
   (...)
   private static final String  ACTION_OPEN                 = "open";
   (...)
    private HelloARRuption helloARRuption
   (...)
   public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
      (...)
      if (RuptionARPlugin.ACTION_OPEN.equals(action)) {
            this.openCallback = callbackContext;

            boolean cameraPermissionRequesrRequired = !cordova.hasPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
            _locationPermissionRequestRequired = !cordova.hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && !cordova.hasPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

            if(cameraPermissionRequesrRequired && _locationPermissionRequestRequired) {
                _cameraPermissionGranted = false;
                this.cordova.requestPermissions(this, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION} );
            } else if (cameraPermissionRequesrRequired) {
                this.cordova.requestPermissions(this, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA});
            } else if (_locationPermissionRequestRequired) {
                _cameraPermissionGranted = true;
                this.cordova.requestPermissions(this, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION});
            } else {
                helloARRuption.onSurfaceCreated(render);
                helloARRuption.onSurfaceChanged(render, width, height);
                helloARRuption.onDrawFrame(render);
            }
            return true;
        }
      (...)
   }
   (...)
   protected static class  HelloARRuption extends HelloArActivity {

       @Override
        public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
           super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

           if(!hasFocus) {
               this.getCurrentFocus();
           }
       }

       @Override
        protected void onResume() {
           super.onResume();
       }
    }

(...)
}
```

On my library file, I have the definition of HelloARActivity classes.

When I generate the plugin and add it to a project, the callback I receive is the error one. I don't know what happens inside the open function.

My Cordova plugin is on https://github.com/ruption-lda/ruption-ar-cordova-plugin

Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you checked after adding `callbackContext.success();` in the else block when app has all the permissions??

Comment: I tried to add the callbackContext.success() but it didn't change the behavior. Still get the callback error